Soundcloud embedding are not working on the site
Some time ago soundcloud links automatically produced an embedded player when added to a question or an answer. Very handy to answer pronunciation questions on the site, which are not uncommon.
An example of this feature working is this answer to RAE pronunciation question, which works and looks like this for me today:

Today, I created a new answer to the question of how cohiba is pronounced, but the link appears in the answer, not the expected embedded player of the sound.

I changed the URL from https:// to http://, as suggested before, but to no avail.

Creo que esta es una pregunta para Big Meta, no el Meta de Spanish.

Desconozco si el error, suponiendo que lo es, se da a nivel general o si es solo en este sitio. Mi post original, el que llevó a que se habilitara aquí, fue en este meta. ¿Por qué crees que debiera hacerlo en el meta global?

Porque este tipo de sugerencias son para el sitio global, por más que se dé en uno en particular, incluso puede que ya se haya realizado la pregunta/sugerencia. Desde este Meta, ni los usuarios ni los moderadores podrían/podríamos hacer nada.

@Danielillo, agradezco tu preocupación, he revisado lo que he podido encontrar de documentación y he consultado con otras personas, y encuentro que lo correcto es hacer aquí la publicación. Podría hacerse en el meta general, pero no haría la diferencia, ya que es específica a este sitio. Si tuviese evidencia que es un bug que afecta varios sitios, entonces si que tendría que publicarlo en el meta general, pero no es el caso. De hecho, el centro de ayuda menciona el reporte de bugs en el privilegio de participación en meta (que es el meta de cada sitio).

Para finalizar, comento que gracias a la ayuda de un miembro del equipo de CM, llegué a este procedimiento para escalar el tema. Para capturar una mayor atención, vendría bien algún soporte de la comunidad también, ya sea en forma de respuestas o en forma de votos a esta publicación.

@Danielillo, algo nuevo que encontré es este post sobre el mismo tema en un sitio diferente, publicado y cerrado en el Big Meta en favor de una publicación en el meta del sitio de marras. La razón de cierre fue: This question is only applicable to one specific site.

Igual sigo pensando que a nivel respuesta, sabiendo que es una funcionalidad del sitio, en cuanto a tráfico generarás más interés en el Meta global que en este. Aquí las visitas no suelen pasar las tres decenas, si llegan. Bien puede que tu objetivo siendo moderador sea generar interés por el sitio, si es así, intentaría con alguna otra alternativa.

This functionality has been restored, you can find more information in my answer on Music Meta.
Apologies for the delay here, and thanks for reporting, we appreciate the help!

Many Thanks @Felippe!
